# Using WHERE NOT EXISTS returns 0 records

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables:
`Table1` looks like:

```
domain  property    property2
------------------------------------
a.com   xx           yy
b.com   zz           jj
c.ocm   dd           rr
```

`Table2` looks like:

```
domain  ip
-------------
a.com   1.1.1
c.com   3.3.3
```

I want to query the `Table1.domain` that does not exists in `Table2.domain`. I tried this command:

```
SELECT `Tabl1`.`domain`
FROM `myschema`.`Table1`
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT `Table2`.`domain` 
FROM `myschema`.`Table2`
WHERE `Table2`.`domain` = `Table1`.`domain`)
```

It returns 0 records. But I know that there are some records in Table1 domains that do not exists in Table2. Can you point to me what is missing?

Comment: your select looks ok. the problem could be some unvisible chars like spaces in names, Tabs or somethink like that. and you have a typo `Tabl1`

Comment: True. It was a problem of table contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT table1.domain 
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.domain NOT IN (SELECT table2.domain FROM table2)
```